# Sending An Email From a .html Page via Calling A .aspx.vb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

I have, hopefully a small, issue that you can help with.

I have an Email.html page which asks the user to enter an email address to which I want to send an email too:

```
<section id="dialog" class="window">
<h1>Email Me <a href="#" class="close"/>Close</a></h1>
```

```
  <p>Email Details To</p>
    <input type="email" placeholder="email address" autofocus class="input-    email" id="email">

  <p id="email-entry" class="error disp-none">Please enter an email address</p>
  <p id="email-valid" class="error disp-none">Please enter a valid email address</p>

  <input type="button" value="Send" id="btn-send">
```

I have an aspx.vb file which I hoped that would ‘take care’ of the emailing:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class ContactUs
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub SendMails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SendMails.Click

Dim FromPersonName As String = FromName.Text
    Dim FromPersonEmail As String = “sales@test.co.uk”
    Dim FromPersonContactNumber As String = FromContactNumber.Text
    Dim EmailSubject As String = Subject.Text
    Dim ToAddress As String = email.input

    '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
    Dim mm As New MailMessage(FromEmail.Text, ToAddress)

    '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
    mm.Subject = Subject.Text
    mm.Body = "Thank you for your enquiry. A member of our team will contact you shortly.”
    mm.IsBodyHtml = False

    '(3) Create the SmtpClient object
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

    '(4) Send the MailMessage (will use the Web.config settings)
    smtp.Send(mm)

    EmailSentForm.Visible = True
    SendMails.Visible = False

End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, a web.config file that access my server:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <!--    <network host="yourRELAYSERVERHOSTNAME" port="yourPORTNUMBER" userName="yourUSERNAME" password="yourPASSWORD" /> -->

        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

How can I integrate these file together (if possible), so when a user enters there email address in the .html page, the .aspx.vb script is called and the web.config?

Is there an easier solution to what I am trying to achieve?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is the SendMails button?

Comment: SendMail button is there: <input type="button" value="Send" id="btn-send">

Comment: You can do it in one page itself by using Asp.Net Server-side button control , if you absolutely need to use html button then you need to use ajax.

Comment: Non of the above have worked so far. AJAX is the preferred route i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called AJAX. I think you just have to modify your aspx code in order to return some kind of response back to your HTML page/AJAX request.

Lets say your aspx page returns `success` as a text if a mail has been sent, simply write:

```
$.get('aspx.vb', {email: $('#email').val()}, function (data) {
   if (data === 'success') {
       alert('Email has been sent successfully');
   } else {
       alert('Oops, There was some problem.');
   }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DDaJQ/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Non of the above have worked so far. AJAX is the preferred route i believe.

Comment: Did u try to pass your aspx page to above function and  put `console.log(data)` inside the callback function. Use firebug or Google Chrome extension to see what you get as a response.